# how do I insert each row of a small dataframe before the matching rows of a big dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one small and one big dataframe

the small one

```
             WS      period shortCode identifier
6        197.78  2023-03-10   TC2-FFA       spot
7        196.79  2023-03-10   TC5-FFA       spot
8        253.13  2023-03-10   TC6-FFA       spot
9        198.13  2023-03-13  TC12-FFA       spot
10       166.67  2023-03-10  TC14-FFA       spot
11       217.86  2023-03-10  TC17-FFA       spot
18        97.00  2023-03-10   TD3-FFA       spot
19       172.19  2023-03-10   TD7-FFA       spot
20       205.71  2023-03-13   TD8-FFA       spot
21       175.63  2023-03-10  TD19-FFA       spot
22       115.45  2023-03-10  TD20-FFA       spot
23  11350000.00  2023-03-10  TD22-FFA       spot
24       232.14  2023-03-10  TD25-FFA       spot
```

the big one with MultiIndex

```
datumUnit                      $/mt       WS
identifier period shortCode                 
TC2BALMO   Mar 23 TC2-FFA    39.376  228.930
TC2CURMON  Mar 23 TC2-FFA    35.946  208.988
TC2+1_M    Apr 23 TC2-FFA    38.444  223.512
TC2+2_M    May 23 TC2-FFA    37.786  219.686
TC2+3_M    Jun 23 TC2-FFA    36.613  212.866
                            ...      ...
TD25+3Q    Q4 23  TD25-FFA   42.909  185.432
TD25+4Q    Q1 24  TD25-FFA   39.000      NaN
TD25+5Q    Q2 24  TD25-FFA   32.421      NaN
TD25+1CAL  Cal 24 TD25-FFA   34.250      NaN
TD25+2CAL  Cal 25 TD25-FFA   33.955      NaN
```

This is its MultiIndex

```
MultiIndex([( 'TC2BALMO', 'Mar 23',  'TC2-FFA'),
            ('TC2CURMON', 'Mar 23',  'TC2-FFA'),
            (  'TC2+1_M', 'Apr 23',  'TC2-FFA'),
                  ...
            (  'TD25+4Q',  'Q1 24', 'TD25-FFA'),
            (  'TD25+5Q',  'Q2 24', 'TD25-FFA'),
            ('TD25+1CAL', 'Cal 24', 'TD25-FFA'),
            ('TD25+2CAL', 'Cal 25', 'TD25-FFA')],
           names=['identifier', 'period', 'shortCode'], length=198)
```

I wish to insert the "spot" line of the small dataframe on top of the 2nd dataframe for each shortCode without changing the order of the big dataframe

intended result

```
datumUnit                      $/mt       WS
identifier period shortCode                 
spot     23-03-10 TC2-FFA      NaN   197.78        
TC2BALMO   Mar 23 TC2-FFA    39.376  228.930
TC2CURMON  Mar 23 TC2-FFA    35.946  208.988
TC2+1_M    Apr 23 TC2-FFA    38.444  223.512
TC2+2_M    May 23 TC2-FFA    37.786  219.686
TC2+3_M    Jun 23 TC2-FFA    36.613  212.866
                            ...      ...
spot     23-03-10 TD25-FFA      NaN   232.14  
TD25BALMO  Mar 23 TD25-FFA   48.902  211.331
TD25CURMON Mar 23 TD25-FFA   53.254  230.138
TD25+1_M   Apr 23 TD25-FFA   46.815  202.312
TD25+2_M   May 23 TD25-FFA   43.717  188.924
TD25+3_M   Jun 23 TD25-FFA   41.571  179.650
TD25+4_M   Jul 23 TD25-FFA   40.776  176.214
TD25+5_M   Aug 23 TD25-FFA   40.281  174.075
TD25CURQ   Q1 23  TD25-FFA   46.668  201.677
TD25+1Q    Q2 23  TD25-FFA   44.035  190.298
TD25+2Q    Q3 23  TD25-FFA   40.367  174.447
TD25+3Q    Q4 23  TD25-FFA   42.909  185.432
TD25+4Q    Q1 24  TD25-FFA   39.000      NaN
TD25+5Q    Q2 24  TD25-FFA   32.421      NaN
TD25+1CAL  Cal 24 TD25-FFA   34.250      NaN
TD25+2CAL  Cal 25 TD25-FFA   33.955      NaN
```

Comment: you could convert the `period` column of the smaller df to the same format as that of the larger one, set it to mult-index as well and the [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and sort by `period` then `shortCode` then `identifier`. Or, if the order is *that* important to you, you could slice and concat....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `shortCode`-blocks in `df` are connected you could try (`df_small` your small dataframe and `df` your main dataframe):

```py
df_small = df_small.set_index("shortCode", drop=False)
df = df.reset_index()
cols = ["identifier", "period", "shortCode", "WS"]
dfs = []
for short_code, sdf in df.groupby("shortCode", sort=False):
    dfs.append(pd.concat([df_small.loc[[short_code], cols], sdf]))
result = (
    pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    .set_index(["identifier", "period", "shortCode"])
)
```

If that is not the case and you want the new row for each connected block then you could try:

```py
df_small = df_small.set_index("shortCode", drop=False)
df = df.reset_index()
cols = ["identifier", "period", "shortCode", "WS"]
dfs = []
groups = df["shortCode"].ne(df["shortCode"].shift()).cumsum()
for _, sdf in df.groupby(groups):
    dfs.append(pd.concat([df_small.loc[[sdf.iat[0, 2]], cols], sdf]))
result = (
    pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
   .set_index(["identifier", "period", "shortCode"])
)
```

Assumption for both versions: there's exactly one `shortCode` in `df_small` for each `shortCode` in `df`.

Result for something similiar to the sample:

```
                                      WS    $/mt
identifier period     shortCode                 
spot       2023-03-10 TC2-FFA    197.780     NaN
TC2BALMO   Mar 23     TC2-FFA    228.930  39.376
TC2CURMON  Mar 23     TC2-FFA    208.988  35.946
TC2+1_M    Apr 23     TC2-FFA    223.512  38.444
TC2+2_M    May 23     TC2-FFA    219.686  37.786
TC2+3_M    Jun 23     TC2-FFA    212.866  36.613
spot       2023-03-10 TD25-FFA   232.140     NaN
TD25BALMO  Mar 23     TD25-FFA   211.331  48.902
TD25CURMON Mar 23     TD25-FFA   230.138  53.254
TD25+3Q    Q4 23      TD25-FFA   185.432  42.909
TD25+4Q    Q1 24      TD25-FFA       NaN  39.000
TD25+5Q    Q2 24      TD25-FFA       NaN  32.421
TD25+1CAL  Cal 24     TD25-FFA       NaN  34.250
TD25+2CAL  Cal 25     TD25-FFA       NaN  33.955
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need to keep the identifiers as they were because there are 2 values for the current months for each category of data, TC2BALMO and TC2CURMON  are both March

Comment: @neutralname Thanks for the feedback. Maybe I don't understand, but doesn't the solution does that?

Comment: @neutralname Now I understand your comment: I've imported `df` the wrong way. The solution is still the same but the result is adjusted.